# How can I change the WSL bash command default directory?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, run-dialog

I have WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) set up on my computer with Ubuntu. 
When I want a Linux session, I hit <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
and type `bash` because it's short and quick. 
However, it always drops me into `/mnt/c/Users/Michael`. 
I want it to drop me into my Ubuntu home directory (`~`) instead.

I've tried adding `cd ~` to my .bash_profile, but then whenever I try to run `bash` from the command line, it *always* takes me to `~`, instead of opening bash in the current directory.

I can get around this by running `ubuntu` from the Run Dialog, but it takes longer and is harder to spell.

How can I get `bash` to open `~` when run from the run dialog, and the current working directory when run from Command Prompt or PowerShell? Or, what are some good workarounds?

Comment: Probably all you need is to create a command (bat, shortcut, whatever) for windows that will force a shell to open where you want (your home).  Than to call it from Dialog. From [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/140635/66388) you can execute the equivalent of a `sh -c 'cd ~/Documents; exec "${SHELL:-sh}"'` (you may want to substitute `sh` with `bash` and delete `Documents` too since you want only `~` )... But I hope you get the hint.

Comment: @Hastur The problem with that is that it will **always** open in that same directory then, even when I run `bash` from the command line.

Comment: I believe that you’ve misunderstood Hastur’s suggestion.  I believe that their suggestion is that you create a batch file with a new name (e.g., `wsl.bat` or `runbash.bat`) containing the `sh -c '…'` command, and then run that from the Run dialog, while continuing to use `bash` from Command Prompt or PowerShell.  Or create a Windows shortcut, and put that in your Start menu or on your desktop.

Comment: Oh, I understand now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple kludge (workaround) would be to put

```
if [ "$PWD" = '/mnt/c/Users/Michael' ]
then
    cd
fi
```

into your `.bash_profile`. 
That way, if you’re in your Windows home directory (`C:\Users\Michael`)
when you run `bash`, it will go to your Ubuntu home directory. 
If you’re anywhere else, it will stay there.

This is a kludge/workaround inasmuch as,
if you manually go to `C:\Users\Michael` in Command Prompt or PowerShell,
`bash` will still `cd` to `~`.